# What method is best used to parse data from a .txt file and store it in an variable to be hashed?

Tags: java, parsing, hash

I am trying to parse data from a file and hash the output data. I can extract the data from a file using multiple methods however I am unable to store the output into a variable for it to get hashed.

What is the best method to extract data?
store the data in a variable?
hash that variable? (I have been using `org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils`)

Can someone please guide me? I am still new to OOP.

I tried using the following method below I get the output from the file:

`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException {
    List<String> stngFile = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader bfredr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader
            ("MyFile.txt"));

    String text = bfredr.readLine();
    while (text != null) {
        stngFile.add(text);
        text = bfredr.readLine();
    }
    bfredr.close();
    String[] array = stngFile.toArray(new String[0]);

    Arrays.toString(array);
    for (String eachstring : array) {
        System.out.println(eachstring);
    }

}


public String calculateHash() {
    return Crypt.calculateHash(array.toString()
            +timestamp.toString()
            + nonce);
}
```

`

How can I take the extracted data and store it in a String variable that I can use to hash that data? The above code gives me Null as the return value.

Comment: I've [already dealt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74450047/what-is-the-best-way-to-hash-lines-from-text-file-using-java) with this. Why did you delete it?

Comment: @g00se I realised I didn’t post the question properly so I was getting answers to irrelevant things. Thank you for your help much appreciated